# dataTable not doesnt display ajax data correct

Tags: javascript, php, json, datatable, datatables

I am using DataTables and want to use Ajax to load my data. But I get this error when I load the page:

DataTables warning: table id=example - Requested unknown parameter 'DocentID' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

I dont know what i'm doing wrong here is my 
Datatables script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#example").DataTable({
    "ajax": {
      "url": "assets/includes/ajax.php",
      "dataSrc": ""
    },
    "columns": [
        {"data": "DocentID"}
    ]
  });
});
```

And my ajax.php file + what it echos

```
include_once('DB_Handler.php');

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT DocentID FROM gebruiker");

$rows = array();
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $rows[] = json_encode($row);
}

echo json_encode($rows);
```

The array :

```
["{\"0\":\"0\",\"DocentID\":\"0\"}","{\"0\":\"67\",\"DocentID\":\"67\"}","{\"0\":\"0\",\"DocentID\":\"0\"}","{\"0\":\"0\",\"DocentID\":\"0\"}"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the first `json_encode()`. There's no need to encode it twice.

```
include_once('DB_Handler.php');

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT DocentID FROM gebruiker");

$rows = array();
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $rows[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: @RubenvandeBunt Glad to help!

Comment: Got another problem i want to use this sql but it doesnt show anything its just blank on ajax.php https://pastebin.com/53Z2VZjn