# Populate text-box/drop-down from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, autofill

I have a mysql table `transaction` with columns `TID`, `UID` and `MOBILE`.How can I populate my textbox with mobile numbers from column `mobile` depending on `UID`, and avoid duplicate values? Just like an autocomplete text-box/drop-down or search.Help is very much appreciated.

> table: transaction

```
>  TID | UID        |  Mobile
>  1   | 001        |  12345678  
>  2   | 002        |  87654321
>  3   | 003        |  22235654
>  4   | 003        |  22235654
>  5   | 001        |  00001556
```

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53723200/datatable-not-doesnt-display-ajax-data-correct) [datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatable+mysql) question/answer.

Answer (score 0):

use the textbox property OnChange(), inside the function run query for select to get the data from the table.